# Is there any cons to use Hibernate for always in place of "Shut down"?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any cons to use Hibernate for always in place of "Shut down"?

I always keep open many programs and many TABS in firefox so i use hibernate.

What type of problem i can face if i use Hibernate always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect world there are no drawbacks. In reality, some software does not release resources correctly and some hardware does not handle resuming from hibernation very well.

If you always use hibernate with software that leaks resources you will end up with a very slow computer. This can be solved with a restart.

If you use hibernate with hardware that does not support resuming from hibernation correctly then that hardware device may not work until a reboot or worse, your entire system may not work until a restart. Modern hardware is pretty good, however.

Long story short: If you're using modern hardware you shouldn't have any problems aside from occasionally having to do a full restart due to leaky software.

Comment: "some software does not release resources correctly" - this happens far too often than not. If you're only hibernating to avoid a slow startup perhaps a trip to msconfig's Startup tab would do your machine some justice, oh and this (http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/02/04/boot-snooze-combines-the-goodness-of-hibernation-and-rebooting/)